# Zooming into a shapefile in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I have a shapefile, but am only interested in displaying a small section of it.  I have the x and y limit coordinates, but have not been successful in plotting it.

This is what I have so far:

```
area<-readOGR("ATSDR","ATSDR")
az_fortify <- fortify(area)

ggplot(az_fortify)+geom_polygon(aes(long,lat,group=group),colour="grey90")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(36.928662, 31.347814))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-114.293736, -109.057855))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with coord_cartesian:

```
ggplot(az_fortify)+geom_polygon(aes(long,lat,group=group),colour="grey90")+ 
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(36.928662, 31.347814)), ylim = c(-114.293736, -109.057855))
```

Comment: This limited the window to the specified latitude and longitude, but the fields we expected to be there from az_fortify could not be seen. Even after broadening the latitude and longitude to the entire US, nothing from az_fortify could be seen.

Comment: @alma Have you checked that the datum is correct? It sounds like either there is a problem with your data or your datum, and the data is plotting somewhere wrong it shouldn't be.